# placeholder javascript fallback for textarea not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The below is the html code:

```
 <textarea name="test" rows="5" cols="20" placeholder="Brief description of your requirement,project, concept or idea"></textarea>

<script>
$(function() {
    function supports_input_placeholder() {
        var i = document.createElement('input');
        return 'placeholder' in i;
    }
    if (!supports_input_placeholder()) {
        var fields = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
        for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            if (fields[i].hasAttribute('placeholder')) {
                fields[i].defaultValue = fields[i].getAttribute('placeholder');
                fields[i].onfocus = function() {
                    if (this.value == this.defaultValue)
                        this.value = '';
                }
                fields[i].onblur = function() {
                    if (this.value == '')
                        this.value = this.defaultValue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Please help me point out the mistake. placeholder fallback functionality is not working.I have been debugging it from long time.

Below is the link for fiddle:
check the functionality in ie9 and below as they doesn't support placeholder attribute:

http://jsfiddle.net/DxcYW/

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: defaultValue is not working i guess

Comment: By not working you mean it is not visible?

Comment: i mean placeholder functionality is not working for browsers which doesn't support it.

Comment: Did you check your browser console for script errors?  Did you do any rudimentary debugging either with breakpoints or with `console.log()` statements to see what path the code was taking and why?

Comment: Please create a fiddle reproducing your issue, Your If condition is never get fired!

Comment: I have done all debuggings and i feel defaultValue works on input types but not textarea.

http://jsfiddle.net/DxcYW/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is in pure JavaScript:

```
(function (D, undefined) {
  'use strict';
  var i, length, placeholder, textareas;
  function hidePlaceHolder (placeholder) {
    return function (e) {
      var target;
      target = e.target || e.srcElement;
      if (target.value === placeholder) {
        target.value = '';
      }
    };
  }
  function showPlaceHolder (placeholder) {
    return function (e) {
      var target;
      target = e.currentTarget || e.srcElement;
      if (target.value === '') {
        target.value = placeholder;
      }
    };
  }
  if (! ('placeholder' in D.createElement('textarea'))) {
    textareas = D.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
    length = textareas.length;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
      placeholder = textareas[i].getAttribute('placeholder');
      textareas[i].value = placeholder;
      if (textareas[i].addEventListener) {
        textareas[i].addEventListener('focus', hidePlaceHolder(placeholder));  
        textareas[i].addEventListener('blur', showPlaceHolder(placeholder));
      } else {
        textareas[i].attachEvent('onfocus', hidePlaceHolder(placeholder));  
        textareas[i].attachEvent('onblur', showPlaceHolder(placeholder));
      }
    }
  }
}(document));
```

Comment: yeah jquery is easier to use but the project I am working are more specific in using javascript for some reason. I am sure about. So could you help me getting the solution in javascript

Answer (score 0):

try putting your JS in

```
    <script> ... </script>
```

tags. :)

Comment: actually that is there i forgot it here

Comment: @susheel I'd rather not have the script tags included. That's just more bulk in the sample code. This is kind of a silly answer.

Comment: please help me solve the problem. My mistake that I forgot it in question in hurry. I corrected it now

Answer (score 0):

My findings and solution:

- Input fields have value attribute but **TEXTAREA** doesn't have it.
- So when we use **inputObj.defaultValue="sometext"** for input tag it sets the default value as well as current value to **sometext,** if we dont define the attribute value="something" in the input tag.This works fine from ie9 and above. For below versions if we don't define value="sometext" **inputObj.defaultValue="sometext"** won't set current value as the default value by itself. For this we can do two things:

  1. we have to manually give value="something which is equal to placeholder text"
  2. we can get the value of placeholder through javascript and set the value from there.
- This is not the case with textarea. Textarea doesn't have a attribute value. So when we use **textareaObj.defaultValue="sometextarea text"** then the default value is set to the given text but not the value itself as we don't have value attribute.value in textarea is nothing but the content between the textarea tags.
- Difference between defaultvalue and value:

  1. default value remains the same once it is set.
  2. value is the current value which is being modified by javascript or ourself my typing into the textfield.

For my above issue I found a workaround just by adding one more line to my code:

```
<textarea name="test" rows="5" cols="20" placeholder="Brief description of your requirement,project, concept or idea"></textarea>

<script>
$(function() {
    function supports_input_placeholder() {
        var i = document.createElement('input');
        return 'placeholder' in i;
    }
    if (!supports_input_placeholder()) {
        var fields = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
        for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            if (fields[i].hasAttribute('placeholder')) {
                fields[i].defaultValue = fields[i].getAttribute('placeholder');
                fields[i].value = fields[i].getAttribute('placeholder');//setting the value    
                fields[i].onfocus = function() {
                    if (this.value == this.defaultValue)
                        this.value = '';
                }
                fields[i].onblur = function() {
                    if (this.value == '')
                        this.value = this.defaultValue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Thank you guys for your quick replies and I pity the guy who voted down the question. I feel it is a good question. isn't it ?